# Restrict access to files being placed by a user to other user

Tags: ftp, shared-folders

I have a folder name **Uploads** in my windows based ftp server. There are two users 'UserA' and 'UserB' who are placing the text files to this **Uploads** folder on daily basis.

How can I restrict file access (open, delete, rename) placed by UserA to UserB and vice versa. or how can I hide files placed by UserA from UserB and vice versa. Please provide some solution, freeware tool etc which does the job. This is important from securty point of view.

Please note, I dont want to make subfolders inside **Uploads** because of business reasons